# Can't log in Ubuntu in a dual boot system

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. Until this moment everything worked fine, but just now when I tried to boot into Ubuntu I failed and I got this message:

Try(hd0,0): EXT2

On the other hand Windows boot just fine as it is proved by the fact that I am able to write this question!

What is happening? How can I fix that so to log into Ubuntu?

Comment: did you change anything in either OS immediately before this happened?  Run any updates?

Comment: @RussellUhl I am not completely sure but I think that there was one update in Ubuntu....I need urgently to be able to at least access some files in that OS!

Comment: what happens if you boot into ubuntu, get that error, and then just sit there and wait for say, 5 minutes? (Obviously not the best solution, but give it a try.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2012900)

Comment: @RussellUhl It just remains there saying this message. I didn't wait for 5 minutes but I think that is will just remain that way...

Comment: If it's urgent, *boot from the Ubuntu 14.04 installation medium*; you should be able to mount the disk[s] to access files, then repair later.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue last week and the answer to a similar question found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188392/unable-to-start-ubuntu-after-installing-updates-stuck-at-try-hd0-0) worked for me. The steps described there are these:

- Use a live CD (Wubi will do too, escape while booting and choose Demo mode) to boot into a working Linux system.
- Get the partition Linux is installed to with gparted (use this partition instead of /dev/sda1 in the next steps).
- Mount the partition: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
- Bind: `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
- `sudo chroot /mnt`
- `grub-install /dev/sda` (sda not sda1, or other bootable disk)
- `grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`
- `update-grub`